# Using the tel protocol for calling in microsoft teams

Tags: html, url-scheme, microsoft-teams, tel

I'm currently building an app for microsoft teams, and i'm having a lot of problems calling with the teams dialer from my third party application. I should start by saying that the tenant i'm testing on at the moment, have the right license and can do external calls just fine. The problem arises when i'm trying to click a tel protocol in my app. When i click the tel protocol i get an infinite loading screen. See below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bL9m.png

This is the code for the tel link: `<a href ="tel:+45*mynumber*"> Call now</a>`

Have anyone encountered a problem like this?

Comment: Could you please try to set Microsoft Teams as as default app for calling inside  'Default apps per protocol' settings on Windows 10 under Settings … Apps?

Comment: Teams should be the default app by protocol for tel and as long as customer can make outgoing PSTN calls through teams this link should work "<a href ="tel:+45*mynumber*"> Call now</a>". Could you please attach logs if you still facing issue to make PSTN calls from teams app?

Comment: Hey Trinetra-MSFT. I was sure to set teams as default for the tel protocol in 'Default apps per protocol', before testing this. Still, the issue remains. I'm as an extension, i'm having some problems with the dialer, where it only shows up in my client AFTER i open and close the settings. I'm not sure if these issues are linked

Comment: Could you please attach logs for your PSTN calls?

Comment: I would send you the PSTN-Usage logs. But it looks like there are non. The testuser i'm using, is created under this domain i logged into in Admin Center, however it's all empty.

Comment: Problem is, the PSTN-calls never go through. It's just stuck loading

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make callto: works in adaptive card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513432/how-to-make-callto-works-in-adaptive-card)

Comment: @KyleDelaney this doesn't solve the issue for a configurable tab

Answer (score 0):

If you can update the `href` attribute, I'd suggest updating it to a deeplink:

[How do I deep link to a Microsoft Teams call from a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68483485/how-do-i-deep-link-to-a-microsoft-teams-call-from-a-web-page/68604993#68604993)