# Botframework not working Action Call in HeroCard

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I want to have a Call button in response Chat over Botframework teams

The doc refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/botframework-sdk/blob/main/specs/botframework-activity/botframework-activity.md#card-action

> An action of type call represents a telephone number that may be
> called.

```
    const buttons = [
    { type: ActionTypes.OpenUrl, title: '1. Open URL', value: encodeURI('http://www.google.com') },
    { type: ActionTypes.Call, title: '2. Call with tel:', value: 'tel:08001323333' },
    { type: ActionTypes.ImBack, title: '3. Uploaded Attachment', value: '3' },
    { type: ActionTypes.Call, title: '4. call without tel:', value: '45456544' },
  ];

  const card = CardFactory.heroCard('', undefined, buttons, {
    text: 'Select your choices.',
  });
```

But the result under Teams desktop app is:
[image: ActionType.Call is missing]

Is there any way to show a "call button" ?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of the Bot Framework schema is channel-specific, especially when it comes to cards. If you'd like to know what card actions Teams specifically supports, you should refer to the Teams docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions

Since Teams does not support call actions, you need to use open-URL instead. Using a `tel` URL won't work, but you can read about that problem and a workaround here: [how to make callto: works in adaptive card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513432/how-to-make-callto-works-in-adaptive-card/62544113#62544113)