# How do I deep link to a Microsoft Teams call from a web page

Tags: html, microsoft-teams

Trying to start a call with a user on teams from a web page. All I have is their email.

I was trying to copy the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generate-a-deep-link-to-a-call

They say to use this format to start a call:  https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=EMAIL_HERE

It starts a call with joe@contoso fine but when I try and use any other email it fails with this message:

[image: my link]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It works for me with valid email address e.g. my colleague but fails when i tried with some random my gmail as email address

Comment: From Doc: Currently, the User ID field supports the Azure AD UserPrincipalName, typically an email address, or in case of a PSTN call, it supports a pstn mri 4:<phonenumber>.

Comment: @Bharat I only have access to their email so can't use a phone number. Not sure what's considered a "valid" email address as all the ones I've tried are attached to teams accounts and logged in

Comment: Oh! so the email addresses are valid. Are they in the same domain? Are you able to make calls through teams for those users?

Comment: @Bharat yeah they're both in the same org and I can make calls using the web app and the teams client

Comment: Strange! Would you like to post your webpage code for more understanding?

Comment: There's no additional code. Just an anchor tag with the above url as the href

Comment: Hi,
This issue seems to be related to Platform. We have raised a bug with concerned team.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify either a upn or a phone number with a 4: prefix as specified in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-an-audio-or-audio-video-call

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=,4:<phonenumber

Note that the upn should be of the user as it exists in the callers AAD, so for guest users you'll need to lookup the guest users upn which will look something like upn#something#@contoso.com

Comment: Using the UserPrincipalName copy pasted from Active Directory, I still get issues.
For a call, it says the link is invalid and for a chat it says it failed to add the user.